# How can I implement a regression of a variable on a function In Python (Nelson-Siegel)

Tags: python, statistics, finance

I'm looking to estimate a Nelson Siegel curve in an attempt to recreate the results of Diebold & Li, 2005.
So far i've been trying to use statsmodels but there doesn't seem to be a way for me actually estimate `y = b1 + b2*(1-exp(lambda*t)/(lambda*t)` etc.

Would anyone be able to shed some light on this? Maybe i'm using the wrong package.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried to look for an implementation on the web with not success... Have you thought about implementing it yourself?

Comment: My python isn't so great unfortunately. I'm guessing there's no way to implement it with existing packages?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. From a quick lookout I haven't found one. If its a well known algorithm it might have an implementation somewhere on the web.

Comment: Same comment as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005881/nonlinear-least-square-with-python-statsmodels. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lmfit/ is a good python package for this. There is still no specific model for nonlinear least squares in statsmodels

Comment: Not familiar with the model, but does this have what you are looking for? https://github.com/MaximumBeings/public/blob/master/NelsonSiegel.py If not, you can probably define the optimization scheme using a different loss function

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the code from above